# Unreadable Intellisense tooltip

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When hovering over a function in VScode the information pops-up using Intellisense. However the information seems very malformed and un-readable:

[image]

For comparison, when using the quick-doc in Pycharm, the information appears readable:

[image]

How can I fix the VScode readability, or is there another way of showing this information?

Answer (score 3):

You can set **Jedi** as your language Server in **Settings.json**, which provides better readability:

```
   "python.languageServer": "Jedi"
```

[image]